# Minify CSS using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to minify multiple CSS files using `preg_replace()`. Actually, I'm only trying to remove any linebreaks/tabs and comments from the file. the following works for me:

```php
$regex = array('{\t|\r|\n}', '{(/\*(.*?)\*/)}');
echo preg_replace($regex, '', file_get_contents($file));
```

But I'd like to do it in a single multiline regex, like this:

```php
$regex = <<<EOF
{(
    \t
|
    \r
|
    \n
|
    /\*(.*?)\*/
)}x
EOF;
echo preg_replace($regex, '', file_get_contents($file));
```

However, this does not do anything at all. Is there any way to use a multiline regex like this? With the `x` flag, multiline expressions should work fine in PHP.

Comment: Better use a compression like *deflate* or *gzip*. That will give you better results.

Comment: An example [regex CSS minifier can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195750/minify-compress-css-with-regex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are utilities available that may fit your needs and save you a potentially buggy regex.

The [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor) supports minification of CSS and javascript files.

You may wish to consider this or other existing options before writing your own.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how you would do that, but here is a script my friend wrote that is pretty fast at minifying CSS:

```
function minimize_css($input)
{
    // Remove comments
    $output = preg_replace('#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $input);
    // Remove whitespace
    $output = preg_replace('/\s*([{}|:;,])\s+/', '$1', $output);
    // Remove trailing whitespace at the start
    $output = preg_replace('/\s\s+(.*)/', '$1', $output);
    // Remove unnecesairy ;'s
    $output = str_replace(';}', '}', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I personally use for CSS:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);<br />
preg_replace('@({)\s+|(\;)\s+|/\*.+?\*\/|\R@is', '$1$2 ', $file_contents);
```

Comment: Please explain which character in your pattern the regex engine is suppose to treat case-insensitively.  There are two instances of unnecessary escaping in your pattern. Of course `preg_replace()` doesn't modify by reference, so it is misleading that the returned value is never used.

Answer (score 0):

```
function minifyCSS($css){
    $css = trim($css);
    $css = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $css);
    $search = array("/\/\*[^!][\d\D]*?\*\/|\t+/","/\s+/", "/\}\s+/");
    $replace = array(null," ", "}\n");
    $css = preg_replace($search, $replace, $css);
    $search = array("/;[\s+]/","/[\s+];/","/\s+\{\\s+/", "/\\:\s+\\#/", "/,\s+/i", "/\\:\s+\\\'/i","/\\:\s+([0-9]+|[A-F]+)/i","/\{\\s+/","/;}/");
    $replace = array(";",";","{", ":#", ",", ":\'", ":$1","{","}");
    $css = preg_replace($search, $replace, $css);
    $css = str_replace("\n", null, $css);
    return $css;    
}
```

---

http://mhameen.blogspot.com/2010/04/crystal-script-manger-for-php.html#links

Comment: Your link is dead. Was this page where you found this code?